# How do I use another partition as home post-installation?

Tags: system-installation, home-directory

I have a home partition from a previous installation that I grew out of (zorin os, really slow boot time) and now I have a kubuntu install that I just recently created. My question is: How do I both transfer the packages from the previous installation (all applications) and use the users from the old home for the new installation? In the past, simply mounting the partition as home has not created the new users, it has simply created a new user during install, and when I've tried creating a second user, deleting the home folder of that user and putting a shortcut to the other folder renamed to the same name, it has not gotten past the logon screen for that user. Is there something that I'm missing here?